# Trying to find the max observation by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have the below code where I am trying to find a patients injury level and whether it is between 1 and 5 or 6 and 10. I have used the 'case when' clause below. The issue is, some patients have multiple injury levels. Is there a way for me to only get the max injury level and ignore the others?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Name,
    PT_ID,
    InjuryDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN InjuryLevel BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS Injury1to5,
    CASE 
        WHEN InjuryLevel BETWEEN 6 AND 10 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS Injury6to10,
    Cost AS totalpaid
FROM
    df1
```

Comment: Be careful using `BETWEEN`, it can be problematic in a number of situations. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the heads up! What is the alternative? Would it be `case when InjuryLevel in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results make SQL questions much clearer.

Comment: In this case using between is probably not a big deal. InjuryLevel >= 1 and InjuryLevel <= 5 would be very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the max injury level per patient and date:

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    PT_ID,
    InjuryDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(InjuryLevel) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS Injury1to5,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(InjuryLevel) BETWEEN 6 AND 10
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS Injury6to10,
    Cost AS totalpaid
FROM
    df1
GROUP BY
    Name, PT_ID, InjuryDate
```

When you group, a column must either be listed in the GROUP BY clause or you must apply an aggregate function to it like MIN, MAX, SUM, etc.

Comment: Although `DISTINCT` shouldn't be necessary with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @DaleK, yes of course, thank you for pointing out. I didn't see it. That's the curse of copy/paste